# Python: Simple way to create worldmap of data distribution

Tags: python, charts, world-map

I am looking for a simple way to create a worldmap in python. For example, let's take the following country data:

```
world_data = {
  'af': 141,
  'bd': 5,
  'by': 2,
  'cn': 10,
  'gm': 90,
  'in': 43,
  'ir': 314}
```

Is there any simple way to create a worldmap with customized coloring and color threshold for this data?

At the moment I am using pygal (see below). Unfortunately, I did not find any way for pygal to print a color legend or define thresholds for the coloring.

```
worldmap_chart = pygal.Worldmap()
worldmap_chart.add('data', world_data)
worldmap_chart
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize any Python data visualization library including :

- http://docs.bokeh.org
- https://github.com/python-visualization/folium

Here's a list of some overviews of tools :

- http://pbpython.com/visualization-tools-1.html
- http://flowingdata.com/tag/python/

The one I prefer is a combination of Python and D3.js which is a Javascript visualization library. Here's an example using a map :

http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2015/01/interactive-data-visualization-d3-dc-python-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks, those libraries look great. But I am looking for a simple solution. At best only requiring a few code lines. Athough it would be nice no iteractivity is required either.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you'll have to use a library, I don't know of a way with only a few lines but I'm sure if you look into any one of those  (I'd recommend bokeh) I'm sure it won't take more than say 10 lines.